# Change orientation fails on iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

This line of code always fail on iOS 9.2 Simulator, but it is ok on iOS 8.4 and iOS 10.1 Simulators

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];
```

It trows this error

**XPC connection interrupted
Terminating since there is no system app.**

I created a new MasterDetail Application in XCode and this is viewDidLoad method in the DetailViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];
    }];
}
```

Comment: where you have written above code? add some code here.

Comment: it is executed in the main thread.
it is ok in in iOS 8.4 and iOS 10.1 Simulators

Comment: can place above code in `viewWillAppear` and check?

Comment: Same result. iOS 9.2 Simulator just freezes.

Comment: There is no problem if i use XCode 7.